# confusion on Get and set methods in java

Tags: java

I am learning get and set methods, I was just wondering if these can only be public, and do they need to be written for every instance variable in a class?

Comment: What's the point if they aren't public

Comment: encapsulation and information hiding , what you do want outsiders see about your class...

Comment: @aaronman The reason to not make them `public` (but instead `protected` would be to prevent the data they manage from begin made publicly available, but allow child implementations the chance to either access/set the data they manage or override it's behavior.

Comment: IMHO you should implement getters and setters, with accessibility based on need, for every data member. I wasn't taught this way, but have read books (C#, but doesn't matter to me) since that recommended it - I tried it and I liked it. It's so easy to auto-generate code today it takes no time. So, in my code, you'll see me using my getters and setters even though I have full access to the members.

Comment: Also, the get and set tags do not mean what you think they do. Not all of them are intuitive. Please glance at them and make sure you're not improperly tagging your posts. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

No.

Many internal variables should never be edited, such as states of computations.

If a field is private and has no getter/setter, it is that way for a reason and is acceptable as long as you don't need to access it outside the class.

If it is public, there's no point, and if protected, it's per-package or subclasses *not necessarily in the same package*.

Without a modifier, it's package-private.

If you want to make a field private and the getter/setter controlled you can use access levels as well.

On that note, if you want, you can perform validation inside a setter to ensure only acceptable values are set. Then, you can either silently reject, return false if the setter is a boolean, or throw an exception in severe circumstances.

Comment: "..and if protected, it's per-package" , and inheritance?

Comment: Still, one should consider using a system like JSR 303 and one of its implementations for validation.  With these, one typically uses annotations to set up validation, but one can override them if one deploys to a system with different business rules.

Comment: @EricJablow IMO JSR303 is overkill for validation that, for instance, an integer is nonnegative for certain operations.

Comment: True.  On the other hand, you might want different minimum and maximum lengths for names depending on where you deploy your application.  That's driven by each customer, usually.

Answer (score 0):

Get and set methods in Java are just normal methods.  They don't have to be `public`, but they wouldn't be very useful if they weren't `public`.

They don't need to be written for every instance variable in a class.  If there are instance variables whose values depend on other values, then it may not make sense for them to have setters, e.g. a `totalPrice` instance variable that depends on a `quantity` instance variable.

If you want instance variables that shouldn't change, i.e they are immutable, then don't provide any set methods at all.

These methods provide your interface to the caller.  They provide the operations on your object that you allow, so that the caller can't set your values to an invalid state, e.g. a `count` of `-1` or a `latitude` of `91` degrees.  This is "encapsulation", or hiding your object's implementation from your caller.

Answer (score 0):

There is no java rule for making getters and setters public but these are made public for a reason.The point of getters and setters is that only they are meant to be used to access the private varialble, which they are getting or setting. This way you provide encapsulation and it will be much easier to refactor or modify your code later.Using getter and setter functions allow for constraints and encapsulation. Lets say x is the radius. shape.x = -10 would not make much sense. Also, if someone tries to set an illegal value, you can print an error, set a default value, or do nothing. It is good practice to make member variables private so they cannot be modified directly by programs using them.

A good article on the usage of getters and setters:

http://java.dzone.com/articles/getter-setter-use-or-not-use-0

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are talking about encapsulation.

The whole point of these methods is for them to be public so that they can pass the value of your variable somewhere else in the application.

For achieving this with many variables, you may consider using 'listeners' (Observer Pattern Theory) which are basically custom interfaces that work with a custom class that contains many of these get and set methods.

More on encapsulation:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(object-oriented_programming)

More on Observer Pattern Theory
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UEtyGP994X0

Answer (score 0):

You need to have public getters and setters for your object to function as a [JavaBean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans).

If you don't have a JavaBean requirement for your objects, then you don't need/have to provide public getters ( and especially setters ) in your classes.

Answer (score 0):

**Basically Yes, and No.**
**Yes,** Get and Set methods (also called "getters" and "setters" or accessor methods) should almost always be public (although they *can* be otherwise -- there's a difference between *can* and *should*).  The point of getters and setters is usually so other classes can access the encapsulated instance variables.
**Exeptions:**

- You might make an accessor method to be `protected` if you only want child
  classes or other classes in the same package to have access to those
  methods.
- You might use a `private` (or `protected`) setter if you want to
  use special logic to set a variable (like concatenating it)
  *and* you don't want other classes to be able to set the
  variable.

**No**, they shouldn't always have accessors.  Sometimes a variable should only have a getter (for instance, if that variable is `final`), and sometimes a variable shouldn't be accessed at all, and therefore you would not give it any accessor methods.

Comment: Or you have private members that you don't want to be exposed and you prefer, like me, to provide getters and setters over directly accessing any members in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Get and set methods were designed originally for JavaBeans, classes stylized so IDEs and application programs can detect what properties the classes have and what event listeners they support.  Through a limited version of reflection called introspection, tools can analyze the classes, and even if the programmer did not want to use `is/get/set` methods he could write `BeanInfo` classes that tell what methods be used instead.

Look at the Javadoc for `java.beans.Introspector`. and `java.beans.BeanInfo`. This provides ways to document additional information, including methods exposed to other tools and metadata about properties.  For example, a `TemperatureGauge` class could expose the minimum and maximum temperature so a Swing program can set the limits of a slider without the programmer looking the information up.

Still, one should not expose more than one has to expose.  You may need to limit access to getters and setters. You may need them for database tools, but you may not want ordinary programming to touch properties. This leads to ideas like OSGI or proxies where methods are limited to specific packages.

For example, one common tactic is to have getters only, to mark variables final, and build objects in the constructor.  For example,

```
public final class Complex {
    private final double re;
    private final double im;
    public Complex(double re, double I'm) {
        this.re = re;
        this.im = im;
    }
    public double getReal() {
        return re;
    }
    // more getters, arithmetic, etc.
}
```

Note that I named the method slightly differently than the variable; that's okay.

On the other hand, there is a style of programming where one eschews getters and writes methods that tell the object what to do.  Consider a `Name` class with `givenName` and `surname` instance variables.  Then, add this method:

```
public void writeFormally(Appendable app) {
    app.append(surname)
       .append(", ")
       .append(givenName);
}
```

You see this sometimes in Model-View-Presenter systems, like GWT and its `HasText` interface.

Unless you are writing code that deals with dependency injection systems or that use reflection to have your objects communicate with database, don't worry about the specifics of getters and setters.  Just do what comes naturally and limit your objects' exposures.  Also, every time you are tempted to write:

```
x.getA().getB().getC().setZ(42);
```

Rewrite the code to get rid of the chain of gets and sets.  Look up the *Law of Demeter* in *The Pragmatic Programmer*.

Answer (score 0):

Use protected if you want only child classes to access the field. However, if you want other classes to access the field, public is the way to go. Your decision should be based on the scope of access.